# mat-autocomplete selected mat-option pass multiple values from selectedItem

Tags: angular, mat-autocomplete

I have a mat-autocomplete that loads table data that is in JSON format and currently maps a single JSON value as the selected "value" when the user selects an item from the autocomplete.

In addition to this value, I also need to pass some other values from this selected item's JSON node, as these values are being written to a database. So I need 3 values from this selected object, not just one.

But I'm not sure how to access those additional JSON properties from the existing interface or if I need to modify the interface to allow those values to be passed as well.

For example, the table data that populates the autocomplete is below and we are currently using the "codeFileType" as the "value" passed when a user selects an item from the autocomplete table:

```
"table-lookups": [
{
  "codeFileType": "NEW_CODE_FILE_TYPE_A",
  "datasource": "A",
  "myAutoCompleteHook": "autocompleLookupTest1",
  "myAutoCompleteParams": [
    {
      "name": "_endpoint",
      "value": "MyCodeFile"
    },
    {
      "name": "_labelKey",
      "value": "code"
    },
    {
      "name": "_valueKey",
      "value": "description"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "codeFileType": "NEW_CODE_FILE_TYPE_B",
  "datasource": "B",
  "myAutoCompleteHook": "autocompleLookupTest2",
  "myAutoCompleteParams": [
    {
      "name": "_endpoint",
      "value": "MyCodeFile"
    },
    {
      "name": "_labelKey",
      "value": "code"
    },
    {
      "name": "_valueKey",
      "value": "description"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "codeFileType": "NEW_CODE_FILE_TYPE_C",
  "datasource": "C",
  "myAutoCompleteHook": "autocompleLookupTest3",
  "myAutoCompleteParams": [
    {
      "name": "_endpoint",
      "value": "MyCodeFile"
    },
    {
      "name": "_labelKey",
      "value": "code"
    },
    {
      "name": "_valueKey",
      "value": "description"
    }
  ]
}
```

],

So, from above JSON, we are mapping the `codeFileType` as the "value" of the select. I also need to access the selected item's "myAutoCompleteHook" and "myAutoCompleteParams" values as well and pass those along with codeFileType as separate data points.

Here is the HTML format of the mat-option element where we are binding the [value] to the valueKey:

```
<mat-option
 *ngFor="let values of filteredResults$ | async; trackBy: trackByFn; index as i"
 [value]="values[tableConfig?.valueKey]"
 [innerHtml]="buildLabelFromValuesChecked(values, isOptionSelected(values[tableConfig?.valueKey]))">
</mat-option>
```

Comment: why not just keep the full data object on the component, and match back the selected value to retrieve the missing info

Comment: So, use [value]="values" and parse out the selected properties from value?

Comment: not the set, just some sort of identifier. So if I wanted an autocomplete like yours, the id would be something unique to each object (like the datasource property), and the parent would have a property for the selected object that would get updated each time the autoselect did. I've done something similar for a user autocomplete, the mat option value was user id, the display was the name & email, and the selected user info on the component was the full user entry, updated when the selected user changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just pass the `index` of the selected item, and access the full object from the array using the `index` number. Easiest thing ever.

```
<mat-option
 *ngFor="let values of filteredResults$ | async; trackBy: trackByFn; index as i"
 [value]="i"
 [innerHtml]="buildLabelFromValuesChecked(values, isOptionSelected(values[tableConfig?.valueKey]))">
</mat-option>
```

component.ts:

```
// function that is assigned to mat-selected
someFunction(index: number) {
  this.selectedItem = this.table-lookups[index]
}
```

I also see you are running the `*ngFor` on `filteredResults$`. If `filteredResults$` is not same as `table-lookups`, then you can bind `value` to `codeFileType` and use `findIndex` or `filter`.

```
[value]="codeFileType"
```

component.ts:

```
// function that is assigned to mat-selected
someFunction(value: string) {

// filter
  this.selectedItem = this.table-lookups.filter((item) => item.codeFileType === value)[0] // since filter returns an array
}

// or findIndex
  const itemIndex = this.table-lookups.findIndex((item) => item.codeFileType === value) // since filter returns an array
  this.selectedItem = this.table-lookups[itemIndex];
}
```

Then you can use `this.selectedItem.myAutoCompleteHook` and `this.selectedItem.myAutoCompleteParams` to access those props.